# Changing border in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have been learning Javascript and I'm a little confused as to why this doesn't work. I'd like it so if you click the div, it creates a red border around it:

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/1szwjnm6/1/)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Generation X</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
    <div id="clickHere" onclick="run()">
        <p>Hello</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
function run() {
    document.getElementById("clickHere").style.border = thick solid red;
    alert("Changed");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make it ..updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1szwjnm6/2/) (you need to wrap it in the head tag)

```
function run(thisObj) {
    thisObj.style.border = "1px solid red"; //or "1px solid #ff000"
    alert("Changed");
}
```

also, rather than getting the reference to element again, simply pass the reference during the time of invocation.

Comment: or maybe at the end of body

Comment: @AminJafari I was talking about his fiddle configuration.

Comment: I've tried this, it doesn't seem to work. Thanks for replying! Guess I don't quite understand your method :p

Comment: @DeanHampson did you checked the fiddle i have attached?

Comment: @DeanHampson there are two changes 1) `thick solid red` is in quotes, 2)  javascript load-type (from drop down in Js section) is used.

Comment: Thanks so much, it's the quotes I was missing. +1

Answer (score 1):

So, instead of putting an `onClick` on div, use a `addEventListener` should be better.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Event_attributes

https://jsfiddle.net/5jsbhbhu/5/

```
var run = function() {
    document.getElementById("clickHere").style.borderColor = "red";
    document.getElementById("clickHere").style.borderWidth = "1px";
    document.getElementById("clickHere").style.borderStyle = "solid";
    alert("Changed");
};

var node = document.getElementById('clickHere');
node.addEventListener('click', run);
```

Comment: Thanks, tony. May I ask; what was the problem exactly? I have no idea how thed event listener made it work.

Comment: I don't know the `onClick` on `div` is standard or not, I've never put that in `div`, as presentation should be separation from business logic.